# Is there a way to check if API is consumable other than making a request to it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am implementing some sort of idle timer and once the timer is out, I will make some calls to the API and update the data. In order to do that I need to make sure API is still consumable. Is there any way to see API is consumable other than making an actual request to it?

Comment: @Jeff what does it depend on? If it helps, API is Restful

Comment: Is there any way to see if [a random internet resource] is still consumable other than making an actual request to it?

Comment: If the API has an endpoint that does nothing, but still returns a 200 OK, then thats what you'd use.

Comment: @Jeff that still involves making a request to the API. To Caner, you won't be able to check without making a request.

Comment: What do you mean by "see API is consumable"?

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't want to make a request to an endpoint that changes stuff when you just want to check for availability.

Comment: I usually just use a /version endpoint on my apis that returns a version number. Serves two purposes: Acts as an endpoint that anyone can request from to check availability, and, of course, it returns the version number so that the entity consuming the api will be informed when a version change happens.

Comment: The HTTP "OPTIONS" method may be what you are looking for, although it is rarely implemented on the server. More info: http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html

Comment: Just use the API and handle the exception if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the author of the API, you could make an endpoint for just that.

Example: `HEAD /api/amionline`. The `HEAD` verb is used because that indicates no request body, and that pretty much nothing matters but getting a `200 OK`.

Example implementation in JS client using jQuery (not tested):

```
var amIOnline = function(opts) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: '/api/amionline'
    }).then(function() {
        opts.yep();
    }, function(xhr) {
        // XHR is the response object containing info about the failed request.
        opts.nope(xhr);
    });
};

// Usage:
amIOnline({
    yep: function() {
        console.log('Connected! Aw yeah!');
    },
    nope: function(xhr) {
        console.log('Not connected. XHR:', xhr);
    }
});
```